# Draw only one indicies from IBO

Tags: arrays, opengl

How can I correctly to draw only one point from elemets array? Code below draws part of array from 0 to selected.

```
class Mesh
{
public:
...
vector <GLuint> indices;
...
}

void renderSelected(GLuint selectedNum)
{
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 
    this->indices[selectedNum] * sizeof(GLuint), 
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 
    0;
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Something like that everytime draw only one the same point.

```
    glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 
    this->indices[selectedNum] * sizeof(GLuint), 
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 
    &this->indices[selectedNum];
```

Comment: What is this->indices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I correctly to draw only one point from elemets array?

Considering that you want to render a single point at a given index. Then you just need to switch it around `this->indices[selectedNum] * sizeof(GLuint)` should be the number of elements you to render. `0` should be the byte offset relative to the buffer of the first element you want rendered.

So in your case `count` would be `1` and the offset (`GLvoid *indices`) would be the byte offset to the index you want (presuming that's `selectedNum`).

```
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)(selectedNum * sizeof(GLuint)));
```

Note that if it was triangles instead, and you wanted to render a single triangle, then the count would be `3` instead of `1`. As a single triangle consists of `3` indices.